# How to test controller using junit5

Tags: java, spring, junit, junit5

I have the following controller:

```
@PostMapping(VALIDATE_CREDENTIALS)
public AuthenticationResponse validateCredentials(@PathVariable final String memberLoginName, @RequestBody UserCredential userCredential)
{
  log.info("validateCredentials:+ validating for memberLoginName={}", memberLoginName);

  UserCredentialDomain userCredentialDomain = credentialMapper.apply(userCredential, memberLoginName);

  AuthenticationResponseDomain authenticationResponse = credentialValidationPort.authenticate(userCredentialDomain);

  AuthenticationResponse convertedResponse = authenticationResponseMapper.apply(authenticationResponse);

  log.info("validateCredentials:- response={}", convertedResponse);
  return convertedResponse;
}
```

The value of `VALIDATE_CREDENTIALS` is `/validate/{username}`.

I'm creating a basic controller test. Just simply mocking it.

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = {AuthenticateMemberController.class})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class})
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class AuthenticateMemberControllerTest
{
@Mock
private CredentialValidationPort credentialValidationPort;

@Mock
private WebApplicationContext wac;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@BeforeEach // For Junit5
public void setup() {
  mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(wac).build();
}

@Test
public void shouldSuccessfullyValidateCredentials() throws Exception
{when(credentialValidationPort.authenticate(buildUserCredential())).thenReturn(buildAuthenticationResponseDomain());

  MvcResult resultActions = mockMvc.perform(post("http://localhost:8080/validate/bob")
                                               .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                               .content("{\"password\":\"dfd\"}"))
                                   .andExpect(status().isOk())
                                   .andReturn();


  AuthenticationResponse response = getResultFromJson(resultActions);

  assertThat(response).as("The response from the controller")
                      .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("success", true);
}

private AuthenticationResponse getResultFromJson(MvcResult result) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, JsonProcessingException
{
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  AuthenticationResponse response = mapper.readValue(result.getResponse().getContentAsString(), AuthenticationResponse.class);
  return response;
}

private AuthenticationResponseDomain buildAuthenticationResponseDomain()
{
  return AuthenticationResponseDomain.builder()
                                     .memberLoginName("bob")
                                     .memberId("123")
                                     .message("")
                                     .success(true)
                                     .build();
}

private UserCredentialDomain buildUserCredential()
{
  return UserCredentialDomain.builder()
                             .password("dfd")
                             .username("bob")
                             .build();
}
}
```

This is my testconfig class:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.kool.exchange.controller")
public class TestConfig
{
@Bean
public CredentialMapper credentialMapper()
{
   return new CredentialMapper();
}
 
@Bean
public AuthenticationResponseMapper authenticationResponseMapper()
{
   return new AuthenticationResponseMapper();
}

@Bean
public CredentialValidationPort mockCredentialValidationPort()
{
   return Mockito.mock(CredentialValidationPort.class);
}
}
```

I am able to call the controller via postman when the application is running but I get assertion error; expected 200 but got 404. I want to know why my test can't pick up the controller? I've tried a variety of different urls but no luck.
I am using jupiter junit 5 and currently on spring 2.4.2.

Comment: with `MockMvc` and `@WebMvcTest` your application will not start the embedded servlet container and listen on a port. It's a mocked servlet environment and with the auto-configured `MockMvc` you only need to path information of the URL (`/validate/bob`). This [`MockMvc` guide](https://rieckpil.de/guide-to-testing-spring-boot-applications-with-mockmvc/) explains this in greater detail.